# Move custom block immediate after nav

Tags: layout, xml, position, custom-block

I created a custom block on the category page to show category title full width after the menu. For that, I created one XML code on `local.xml` of the theme layout file.

```
<catalog_category_default>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="categpry_page_info" as="topCategoriInfo"
                           template="page/category_info.phtml" before="category.products"/>
    </reference>
     </catalog_category_default>
     <catalog_category_layered>
       <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="categpry_page_info" as="topCategoriInfo"
                           template="page/category_info.phtml" before="category.products"/>
     </reference>
     </catalog_category_layered>
```

and created one file `category_info.phtml` in page folder.

Now whatever I write in this file comes out but it stays inside the container, while I want it to be full width. Is there a way to move the block immediately after the menu so it can come out of that fixed-width container?

Answer (score 3):

Use `top.container` instead of `content` as a reference.

`top.container` is a container within the header element, just below the top menu.